# Compile mbstring statically into PHP

Tags: php-7, php-7.1, php-7.2, mbstring, php-7.0

Is there a way to compile the PHP extension `mbstring` statically into PHP (PHP >= 7)? Something like `./configure [...] --enable-mbstring=static [...] && make`?

Comment: Have you actually tried `./configure --enable-mbstring` ? It embeds the extension into the PHP binary.

Comment: @IVOGELOV: Yes, I tried this. But I have the problem, that I compile PHP on my own and I need now also the `mbstring.so`, but I cannot find any information, how to the this `mbstring.so`. When I install it with `yum install php-mbstring`, I only get the one compiled against `PHP 5.6`.

Comment: When you embed the extension - there is no `mbstring.so`, only `php`. If you do not embed the extension but compile it separately - then you get the SO file but in this case you must add it as `extension=mbstring.so` in your `php.ini`

Comment: @IVOGELOV Do you know how to embed `mbstring` into PHP? This is what my initial question is about...

Comment: Yes - you simply issue `./configure --enable-mbstring && make` and you have a `php` binary with `mbstring` embedded inside it.

Comment: I configure like this with -enable-mbstring  and rebuild `composer` and still get errors like this with composer: `stefanak-michal/bolt v2.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mbstring extension.`